# How can I show the index of two same number in a given array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a function with the parameters (number, target) that returns the index of two numbers in a given array that is equal to sum of the target. Here's the code so far:

```
   const twoSum = function (nums, target) {

    let num1;
    let num2;
    let index1;
    let index2;

    for(let i = 0;  i < nums.length; i++){
      
        num1 = nums[i];
        num2 = target - num1;
       
        if(nums.includes(num2){
            index1 = nums.indexOf(num2);
            index2 = nums.indexOf(num1);
        }
    
    }
    return [index1, index2];
}
```

The problem is; when the array consists of like numbers, it returns just the index of the first number twice e.g `twoSum([5,5,3], 10)` returns `[0,0]` instead of `[0,1]`

Comment: Can you please describe what problem you want to solve? may be you will get a better solution.

Comment: I thought I did in the last sentence after the code. Sorry, English isn't my first language and I'm also new to programming and stack overflow in general

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you are looking for, but this will give you what you described.

```
const twoSum = function (nums, target) {

    let num1;
    let num2;
    let index1;
    let index2;

    for(let i = 0;  i < nums.length; i++) {
      
        num1 = nums[i];
        num2 = target - num1;
       
        if(nums.includes(num2)) {
            index1 = nums.indexOf(num1);
            if(num1 === num2) {
                index2 = nums.findIndex((num, i) => num === num2 && i != index1);
                if(index2 === -1) return -1; //returns -1 if no second number was found
            } else {
                index2 = nums.indexOf(num2); 
            }
            return [index1, index2]; 
        }
    
    }
}
```